# Aplicar funcion de manera más eficiente. Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Tengo un `dataframe` muy pesado que es leído con R y ejecuta una operacion simple:

```
var = ifelse(columna1=="value",columna2,0)
```

Es decir, para todas las filas en que `columna1` tenga el valor `value`, les asigna el valor de `columna2`, caso contrario asigna 0.

Entonces estoy intentando hacer el mismo proceso en python. Mi código es el siguiente:

```
var = df[["columna1","columna2"]].apply(lambda x: x[1] if x[0]=="value" else 0)
```

Pero no me parece muy efectivo ya que la `lambda` no es vetorizada.

Se me ocurre algo como:

`df["columna1"].map({"value": lambda x: x.SUMA_ASEGURADA,"cualquier otro" : 0})`

o algo que aplique, eficientemente, la misma operacion que el `ifelse` de R.

Muchas gracias de por si por sus aportes

**Nota**

Otra cosa rápida que se me ocurre es inicializar `var` con 0:

```
var = df["columna2"] - df["columna2"]
```

Luego usar una asignación por indices:

```
ind = df["columna1"].apply(lambda x: x=="value")
var[ind] == df.loc[ind]["columna2]
```

Pero sé que el segundo código está mal escrito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré una forma eficiente usando `numpy`, la sintaxis es muy similar.

```
import numpy as np
var = np.where(df.columna1 == "value",df.columna2,0)
```